# Take Stream<List> data from multiple collections

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

The place I marked change over time. And I can't know how many places exist now.  It is a chat contact of two users talking about a product.  I can't do just users/senderId/chats/receiverUserId, because two users can talk about another product and this must be another chat contact (chat contact has last message, product Image ...),

or any other suggestion  to achieve this ?

I want to take all fields as Stream List ,

users/user1/chats/user6/products/product1

users/user1/chats/user6/products/product37

users/user1/chats/user6/products/product2

users/user1/chats/user17/products/product789
.
.

users/user1/chats/user19/products/product78
.
.

[image: text]

[image: text]

Answer (score 0):

If all these documents in `products` collection have something in common, you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to select documents across all of them.

For example, if there's a field identifying the product in each `products` document, you can do:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup("products")
    .where("product", isEqualTo: "productYouWantToShow")
    .snapshots()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74061790/stream-brings-the-data-only-momentarily-in-the-beginning , is there any possibility that this problem arose from this solution?

Comment: I don't know. If that question is still about the same problem, don't add it as a new post please. Instead edit *this* question (there's an edit link right under it) to add the new information.